# Glass Mapper Save for a specific language Modifies English language

Tags: glass-mapper

When I am saving the Sitecore item using the below code.

```
app.Language = itemLanguage;
service.Save<Application>(app);
```

It is saving in the respective language but modifying the values in the English version as well.

Comment: Which version of Glass Mapper do you use?

Comment: which values are being modified in english? Can you give an example of the full model?